# How to tell PULP_CBC_CMD to report the first feasible solution

Tags: python, linear-programming

I found a way to set the relative gap and max time for this `pulp` solver:

https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/technical/solvers.html

(see the section about pulp.apis.PULP_CBC_CMD)

However, the `R` version of CBC allows to set an option such that the solver reports the first feasible solution (it's called `maxso` in `rcbc`), but I can't see it here.

**Does anyone have any idea where I could find any documentation about it?**

It was already extremely difficult to find the above webpage in the `pulp` documentation, but the option I am looking for is not there, and regarding 'additional options' it only says:

> options (list) – list of additional options to pass to solver

Then what these additional options are, and how they can be set up, I am at a complete loss finding it out.

Comment: *"Report"* sounds misleading as it's probably more of a stop-condition / limit. I would try to use the common CLI options from Cbc and if not working: crawl pulps sources to see how these are wrapped. [sollim=1](https://www.gams.com/34/docs/S_CBC.html#CBCsollim) sounds like it's worth to try. (I'm assuming, that the (awesome GAMS doc linked) reflects vanilla Cbc you are using, but i would be surprised if not)

Comment: Thanks @sascha ! I will give a shot to `sollim` then. Vanilla or not, this is the only thing I know how to do... if I have to use python I probably have to use `pulp`, given that everything else I tried failed (there is a post about that, which you also contributed to, I believe), and in `pulp` the support for `CBC` is via this `PULP_CBC_CMD` thing. I may be wrong of course, and there might be very sophisticated ways of calling CBC from `pulp` in some other different way. I'll try those if/when I get a degree in computer science :( :)